# How to create a simple share linkedIn link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, linkedin-api

I am using the followings for twitter, facebook and google+ but the linkedin gives me an error dialog box:

```
<a class="btn btn-default icon" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open( 'http://www.twitter.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0, status=0, width=626, height=436');return false;" title="Share on Twitter"><span class="character">a</span></a>

<a class="btn btn-default icon" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open( 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0, status=0, width=626, height=436');return false;" title="Share on Facebook"><span class="character">b</span></a>

<a class="btn btn-default icon" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open( 'https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0, status=0, width=626, height=436');return false;" title="Share on Google+"><span class="character">c</span></a>

<a class="btn btn-default icon" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open( 'https://www.linkedin.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0, status=0, width=626, height=436');return false;" title="Share on Google+"><span class="character">j</span></a>
```

**Error**

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
>   with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<WSResponse>
  <responseInfo>FAILURE_NO_SUBMIT_ACTION</responseInfo> <responseMsg/>
  <jsonPayLoad/> 
</WSResponse>
```

**Note**

> `<?php the_permalink(); ?>` renders the link of the current site page
>   that you could share on socials networks

Comment: error comes from the webservice you call, so it isn't js or jquery issue for me. Please provide us the call to the webservice that gives you this error

Comment: not sure what that error means, do you know how to create a share link with js for linkedIn?

Comment: what is the the_permalink(); for linkedin? what is the result/render of this php page in html?

Comment: the <?php the_permalink(); ?> renders the link of the current site page that you could share on socials networks - I'll update the question with this info

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the problem is you are not doing it in the way linkedin asked to you. You should always refer to API docs first. For example below linkedin describe how you can generate Share Plugin for your site.

[Share Plugin Generator](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share)

and the code generated is looks like:

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
<script type="IN/Share" data-url="Your_URL_Here" data-counter="top"></script>
```

Also you can do it in following way:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://developer.linkedin.com&title=LinkedIn%20Developer%20Network&summary=My%20favorite%20developer%20program&source=LinkedIn
```

Reference: [Share on Linkedin](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin)

Your link will look like:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&title=Some%20Title&summary=Some%20Summary&source=YourWebsiteName
```

Where mini parameter is for: A required argument who's value must always be:  true

and Source is: The url-encoded source of the content (e.g. your website or application name)
Please let me know if you still needs to know how it will work for you.

And all parameters must be URL Encoded.

Comment: i see... so how do i generate the link afterwards?

Comment: Please look into Share on Linkedin link I gave to you. It has URL that you need to use. and ignore Share Plugin Generator

Comment: Please be careful.if  URL has Special characters((persian or arabic ...font)) you can not share it in linkedin

Answer (score 7):

I use this very simple sharer:

```
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=your-url-here.com"target="_blank" title="Share on LinkedIn">
Share on LinkedIn
</a>
```

This is how it looks like:
[Example of using simple LinkedIn sharer in Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdB6w.png)

Answer (score 5):

You can just change in onclick url linkedin 'share?url=' to 'shareArticle?mini=true&', i think it's help.

```
<a class="btn btn-default icon" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open( 'http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0, status=0, width=626, height=436');return false;" title="Linkedin"><span class="character">j</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1 - Get the URL Right**

Use this URL format...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: [**Official MSD LinkedIn Share Documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)

**Step 2 - Handle title, description, image, etc.**

Set your `og:` tags in the `<head>` block of your HTML, like so...

- `<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article'/>`
- `<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg'/>`
- `<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview'/>`
- `<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article' />`

Source: [**LinkedIn Share Documentation: Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn**](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)

**Step 3 - Verify Everything Went Okay**

Use the **[LinkedIn Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/)**.  Insert your URL here (`example.com`), not the URL you are going to share with (`linkedin.com?url=example.com`).

Answer (score 0):

You should better use the linkeidn script, or see what he generate exactly

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
<script type="IN/Share" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-counter="top"></script>
```

source: [linkedin developper](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share)

Answer (score 0):

This script to be added at the top

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang:en_US</script>
```

and if you want to use linkedin button on a popup then you have to insert following script in the html.

```
<script type="IN/Share" data-url="http://linkedin.com">
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this style on my blogger posts

```html
<a style="text-decoration:none;color: #0095ff;display: flex; flex-wrap: nowrap; align-content: center; justify-content: flex-start; align-items: flex-end; background-color: #f3f3f3; border: 4px solid #ededed; width: fit-content; padding: 2px; border-radius: 10px;" href="https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https://www.muratatasoy.com.tr/2023/04/tum-resimleri-powerpoint-slaytlarna.html" target="_blank" title="Share on LinkedIn">
Linked<svg height="24px" preserveaspectratio="xMinYMin meet" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" x="0" y="0"><g style="fill: currentcolor;"><rect height="24" style="fill: none;" width="24" x="-0.003"></rect><path d="M20,2h-16c-1.1,0-2,0.9-2,2v16c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h16c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2V4C22,2.9,21.1,2,20,2zM8,19h-3v-9h3V19zM6.5,8.8C5.5,8.8,4.7,8,4.7,7s0.8-1.8,1.8-1.8S8.3,6,8.3,7S7.5,8.8,6.5,8.8zM19,19h-3v-4c0-1.4-0.6-2-1.5-2c-1.1,0-1.5,0.8-1.5,2.2V19h-3v-9h2.9v1.1c0.5-0.7,1.4-1.3,2.6-1.3c2.3,0,3.5,1.1,3.5,3.7V19z"></path></g></svg></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

I got it to work like this (very simple):

```
 <a target="_blank" title="Share on LinkedIn"
     href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={{your-content-here.com}}">
 </a>
```

this will open a new tab (at least in Chrome), and looks like this:

[image]

In my case,  is a link to Chrome Webstorm item url. Because I'd like share my Chrome Extension App, on various social media sites.